# How to make a page non secure in GWT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I have a page called Customer Signup page which should be accessible without authenticating/logging-in (non secure). Normally I can define a security constraint specific to a JSP or HTML page. But in my GWT app I used the Composite class and ui.xml as template.

This is how the link looks like
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997#Customer%20Signup

Here is my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure section</web-resource-name>
        <description />
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description />
        <role-name>ROLE_ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to exclude one page or path in your application from the constraint? You do not want to change the url-pattern to /secure/* but rather add an exclude to /insecure/* path, correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to exclude one page. But my concern in GWT was that I don't have JSP page. The page was actually written in Java (using Composite or Widget class) so I'm not sure how to define the URL pattern in web.xml

Comment: The page is embedded in a jsp or Html or whatever as a javascript script tag. This loads the so called endpoint. that is the uri you need to exclude. as a hint, just look at the browser's address bar

Comment: Hi thst, sorry for the late reply. I just created a new module and put my page there. This module was set as non secure through the security constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another security constraint with relaxed `<auth-constraint>` (or none) settings. The URL pattern must be more specific than the protective one.

So, this should work:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secure section</web-resource-name>
    <description />
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <description />
    <role-name>ROLE_ADMIN</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secure section</web-resource-name>
    <description />
    <url-pattern>/signup.jsp</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

The second constraint overrules the first constraint on the `signup.jsp` page, because it is more specific. I have never tried to extend the url-pattern to a place definition, that is after the `#` sign, but I suppose this will not work, as the request parameters are in front. So, you should make a new page for the signup.

The J2EE docs specify the section here and the URL-pattern is said to be matched against the request-URI, which in turn is the part after the hostname/port - so it should include the fragment. Given that, matching an anchor in the path *should* work after all.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-17

UPDATE: Maybe I have an idea for you: If I get you right, you want a login page that is part of the application. The problem here is, that you have the same URI for the whole application. But you can protect your backend services with the url-pattern, so that you cannot use the backend without having setup the credentials.

In that case, your loginpage is loaded and the application calls the server for initial data loading. The data loading will fail, because you are not yet logged in. The `onFailure` code must recognize the special failure (no credentials) and show the login view.
The login view will call the unprotected (or excluded) backend servlet for login and prepare the user credentials in the session.

Then you return to your initial place in the application, now with a proper user in the session, and your backend call will succeed.

That should solve the problem.